# What is layout indicates in view page of nopcommerce 3.90?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce-3.90

I want to know that what is layout in view page of nopcommerce which given the path of other view page. But if I remove that layout then also there is no change in nopcommerce.

Like in index.cshtml there is `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ColumnsOne.cshtml";`.

Now, my question is why this other cshtml path has given, and if I remove this line then why is there no change in nopcommerce?

Comment: as of current the question seems very vague, please share more information

Answer (score 2):

The **`Layout`** property allows you to configure a "parent" view, the system renders the views from parent, in your case `_Root.Head.cshtml -> _Root.cshtml -> _ColumnsOne.cshtml -> Index.cshtml`, inside every layout cshtml you can find a `@RenderBody()` call where the child view is rendered.

When you remove the layout line inside `Index.cshtml` the system looks for the a default value and that value is configured inside the **`_ViewStart.cshtml`**, and this layout has configured the `_ColumnsOne.cshtml`, thats the reason that you cant see any changes.

The content of the `_ViewStart.cshtml`

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ColumnsOne.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: so if I am not declared the layout in index.cshtml page. Then its okay or not? If not then please give the reason.

Comment: both options are ok by now the result will be the same, but keep in mind that not declaring the Layout will use the value configured in _ViewStart so if you change that layout you are changing also the Index.cshtm view.

Comment: got it. Btw at the first time run nopcommerce project at that time it shows the installation page. Do you know that where it is declare that at the first time installation page want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Into nopcommerce layout means a master page.

That can be used into all pages as master layout.

If you remove that line than nopcommerce affect design layout.

If your design is not change than this page called as partial page, means call with in any other view page.